# Firefox for Ubuntu add-ons

Tags: firefox, plugins

I am considering to install Ubunta on my PC. Currently also have firefox for windows installed with a number of add-ons. Are those same add-ons available under Ubuntu?

Comment: This question is too broad unless you list the add-ons.

Comment: Some will work, others won't. Depends on your extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Ubuntu at work, OSX at home. I can use most addons on both systems. You can download the live-cd, run that from dvd/cd or usb, startup firefox, install all addons you want, and see what works and what not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. That seems to be the best way. I had the intention of checking out Ubuntu that way too so that dovetails nicely :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say both via the Software Center or the webbrowser,it depends on the add on.

- If you want to keep on the outside of the envelope, use the built-in add on manager. Add ons installed this way will be updated frequently, and you will get major version updates.
- If you prefer a bit of stability, use the ones from the repositories. They are (mostly) very heavily tested and pretty much guaranteed to work really well.

  Add Ons installed from the repositories are not updated between major versions, they only get security and bugfix updates. This is a big plus for stability.

  The ones provided by canonical are also eligible for canonical's enterprise support, if you're interested in that sort of thing.

Needless to say, anything that is operating-system dependent (e.g. ubufox) should be installed from the repositories. The same goes for security-related add ons (even though the only one I can think of is pwdhash). There's no harm (at all) in installing all else via the add on manager.

How can I migrate well from my former add-ons without losing all my preferences?

If you just remove the items from the software centre, your preferences should be kept. But the add on needs to be aware of previous settings, so it may not always work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I do make the switch to Ubuntu, this answer will help me decide how to approach the various installation possibilities, providing of course the Ubuntu equivalent of my Windows version are available.